# Is solang stable enough to use in production?

Tags: solang

I recently came across solang after spending a lot of time in learning anchor and rust for writing smart contracts.

I felt solang as good goto option when compared to rust anchor, As it is very similar to solidity except some minor changes.

But all I want to know is, How stable is solang so that we can use in the production ?

If we are using solang intead of rust what are the caveats we need to keep in our mind and what are the potentials issues me might come across ?

Answer (score 3):

Solang support is relative new to Solana, however:

- We have been working on this project for many years now - writing a new compiler is a large effort
- We've had three security audits by Trail of Bits, which have covered all the security critical parts of the compiler. The [first report is public](https://github.com/solana-labs/security-audits/blob/master/solang/Trail_of_Bits_Solang_Final_report.pdf), the others will also be made public soon.
- There is a dedicated team at Solana Labs working full time on Solang. Our aim is to have Solidity as a fully supported language for Solana and have it a stable language of course. We're [expanding the team](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/3691405120/).
- There are also Polkadot developers working Hyperledger Solang (for the Polkadot wasm target).
- Please ask questions on our [Discord server](https://discord.gg/hyperledger) and on stack exchange, we want to make Solang succeed.